# Spring Boot: can't load file from resources

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have few files with SQL queries in my Spring Boot project. These queries are located by path

```
spring-boot-sql-in-files/src/main/resources/sql/query.sql
```

When I run my application I execute loading of these queries to static variables.

```
private static final String PATH_PREFIX = "src/main/resources/sql/";

public static String loadQueryFromFile(@NonNull String fileName) {
    try {
        return FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(PATH_PREFIX + fileName), Charset.defaultCharset());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error occurred during loading sql file to string, file=" + fileName, e);
        throw new QueryNotLoadedException();
    }
}
```

It works fine when I run it using IDE but it doesn't work when I run `name.jar` file, I get the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'src/main/resources/sql/query.sql' does not exist
```

How can I fix this path?

Comment: Have you verified that the files are present in the jar file?

Comment: Ofcourse it won't run... `src/main/resources` is the root of your classpath. Which will also make that `FileUtils.readFileToString` won't work as it isn't a `File` when packaged as a jar. Instead use the Spring resource abstraction and utils to load it into a string.

Comment: @neuhaus, I have verified, it folder is located `/BOOT-INF/classes/sql/`

Comment: Use @Value(value = "classpath: sql/query.sql")
private Resource companiesXml; 
then use the below code in your method to get a stream
and companiesXml.getInputStream() ...Let me if it helps

Comment: try with `new ClassPathResource("/sql/query.sql").getFile();` to get the file.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza That won't work as it isn't a `File` when packaged inside a `jar`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`src/main/resources` like `src/main/java` becomes the root of your classpath and as such won't work. It won't work with only `sql` as well as it isn't a file when packaged as a `jar`. Instead use the Spring `Resource` abstraction to load the file and the `StreamUtils` to load it into a `String`.

```
public static String loadQueryFromFile(@NonNull String fileName) {
    try {
        Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("sql/" + fileName);
        return StreamUtils.copyToString(resource.getInputStream(), Charset.defaultCharset());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.error("Error occurred during loading sql file to string, file=" + fileName, e);
        throw new QueryNotLoadedException();
    }
}
```

Something like that should do the trick.